# How to write a Map-Method for ParallelQuery without defeating its purpose?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, extension-methods, parallel-processing

I'd like to write a Map-Extension Method for ParallelQuery without destroying the parallelism. Problem is, I have no idea how. I am using ParallelQuery because I'm confident the Multithreading will boost my performance, here's my code so far:

```
public static List<T2> Map<T, T2>(this ParallelQuery<T> source, Func<T, T2> func)
{
    List<T2> result = new List<T2>();
    foreach(T item in source)
    {
        result.Add(func(item));
    }
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, this kind of defeats the purpose of parallelism if I am correct. How would I do this correctly?

Thanks to Dykam for pointing out the the `Select`-Method has exactly the behaviour I want. However, just for learning purposes I'd like to see how exactly this'd work, thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383966.aspx - what I linked is an actual map method, what you wrote both maps and aggregates it into one list. Indeed not parallel.

Comment: I don't know if it'll help your problem but you should probably be using `yield return` instead of building the list in your extension method.

Comment: @Dykam +1 I started to wonder why the OP bothered to write his own `Select()`. Then I opened your link...

Comment: Yes, right, @Dykam, you would answer my question using the Select-Method. However, just for the jist of it I'd like to see how to build an extension method for learning purposes, do we have anything on that? I also updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @DennisRöttger, here is Mono's implmentation: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/f5dbc1ee5568ea24e07b155361a011ad07b3362e/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs#L196 refers to https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/f5dbc1ee5568ea24e07b155361a011ad07b3362e/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq.Parallel.QueryNodes/QuerySelectNode.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question piqued my developer's heart, so I picked it up again and came up with this one:

```
public static IEnumerable<T2> Map<T,T2>(this ParallelQuery<T> source, Func<T,T2> func)
{
    var list = new ConcurrentBag<T2>();
    source.ForAll(s => list.Add(func(s)));
    return list.ToList();
}
```

The `ForAll` loops through the `source` query in parallel and adds the result to a thread-safe collection.

I keep this one in mind when I need Select-like behaviour with some personal twist. It may be an efficient approach when function `func` is a relatively heavy process.